# Change a Linq object inside foreach statement?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

Consider this where I have a class of Linq table in which I want to query this object in foreach statement:

```
      IQueryable< tab_policy> Result=from c in db.tab_policy select c;

      foreach(int i=0;i<3;i++)
      {
      Result = from c in Result
                 join d in db.tab_reg_type_one_to_many.Where(a => a.reg_id==i)
                on c.poli_id equals d.poli_id
                 select c;
       }
```

How can I change Result variable in each iteration based on value of previous iteration??? 
Value I get in this example only equals to the last iteration not all iterations together, while in this case in each iteration Result is changing inside foreach.
While when I use this iteration without foreach like follow it works correctly.

```
       Result = from c in Result
                 join d in db.tab_reg_type_one_to_many.Where(a => a.reg_id==0)
                on c.poli_id equals d.poli_id
                 select c;
      Result = from c in Result
                 join d in db.tab_reg_type_one_to_many.Where(a => a.reg_id==1)
                on c.poli_id equals d.poli_id
                 select c;
      Result = from c in Result
                 join d in db.tab_reg_type_one_to_many.Where(a => a.reg_id==2)
                on c.poli_id equals d.poli_id
                 select c;
```

Comment: That foreach statement wont work, you are confusing the foreach and the standard for syntax.

Comment: Please provide code that actually compiles.

Comment: I'm not sure where you problem is to be honest.  Looking at what I think the code is supposed to do and what I think you want it to do, it seems to be working (with the exception of the syntax issues).  It is processing the results based on the previous linq statement.

Comment: Please cleanup your code. If you have already i changing from 0 to 2, this code can be written for sure without a foreach.

Comment: for each statement work but result is wrong, I intend to update  Result based on previous value got from last iteration.

Comment: I need to write this code with foreach, in original code I don't know values of i, so it may change based on another input.

Answer (score 2):

The technical cause of your problem is that the loop variable `i` is captured in each `Where` delegate but modified in each iteration. Which means: when the query is executed (after the loop) only the last value of `i` is used. This could be solved by something like `var j = i` and using `j` in the `Where`.

But the real solution is much simpler:

```
var ids = Enumerable.Range(0,i).ToList();
Result = from c in Result
         join d in db.tab_reg_type_one_to_many.Where(a => ids.Contains(a.reg_id))
             on c.poli_id equals d.poli_id
         select c;
```

**Edit**
As you correctly comment, this solution is different than 3 joins. The difference is subtle and elusive. With three (or `n`) joins you grab records where `c.poli_id` equals a `d.poli_id` three times, in stead of 1 - 3 times. So after all the solution is to prevent the modified closure:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    var j = i;
    Result = from c in Result
             join d in db.tab_reg_type_one_to_many.Where(a => a.reg_id == j)
                on c.poli_id equals d.poli_id
             select c;
}
```

Comment: I have an FxCop rule that detects such issues in my http://fxcopcontrib.codeplex.com/ project...

Comment: I need to find records in result table which contains all values from ids, for example I want to find those records which has ids=0, ids=1. ids=2 together. current result find all records which have ids=1, or ids=1, or ids=2.

Comment: @Kamran isn't that exactly what Gert's answer is doing for you?

Comment: I want to find records which have all ids together, not other records that may have any of those in ids.

Comment: @GertArnold what is the point of putting i in j when you're not using i and not changing j?

Comment: Not changing `j`, that's the point! Now each lambda expression (a => a.reg_id == j) closes in its own value in stead of all having the same value after the last loop ieteration. Read about "modified closures" to understand this.

Comment: @Gert Arnold see my answer to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

@GertArnold thanks for your answer. this solution is not also correct. instead I replaced IQueryable with List and problem is solved, because IQueryable is calculated when needed, so it is calculated by delay, but List is not like that, so the final solution is:

```
  List<tab_policy> Result = (from c in db.tab_policy select c).ToList();
  foreach(int i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
  Result = from c in Result
             join d in db.tab_reg_type_one_to_many.Where(a => a.reg_id==i)
            on c.poli_id equals d.poli_id
             select c;
   }
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't see how you can join `db.tab_reg_type_one_to_many` with a local list, nor how you can assign an `IEnumerable` to `Result`. There should at leas be a `ToList()` in each iteration. Further: this is a sub optimal solution because you dump the whole `tab_policy` table into memory. Deferred execution is one of linq's strengths. I don't understand why my solution did not work. Technically it is 100% equivalent to your three consecutive statements.